# Screen Size Issue For an Image in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode6

I simply want to display a title page to a game. I want to use pre-rendered images. It needs to work with all iPhones and iPads. So far I am using these assets as screenshot below[image]

I have used these sizes:
In 1x place image with resolution of 320 x 480. 
In 2x place image with resolution of 640 x 960. 
In Retina 4 2x place image with resolution of 640 x 1136. 
In 3x place image with resolution of 1242 x 2207.

Only the iPhone 4 and 5's show correctly. Both 6 and 6Plus are completely wrong.

for iPad:

1x image of 760*1024
2x image of 1536*2048

Only the iPad 2 displays correct. The Air and Retina are completely wrong.

I have read through all the documentation I can find both on here and searching for hours on Google. I am unsure what simple thing I must be overlooking. Am I trying to do something that is not possible? I am only testing on the simulator and thinking it could be an issue with that?

Also I may have a misunderstanding then as I was under the impression that @3x was for iPhone 6 and 6+. If not, what are @3x for?

Comment: Shouldn't @3x be of size 960 x 1704, i.e. (640 / 2 * 3) x (1136 / 2 * 3)?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Image Sets in Asset Catalogs do not include a size for iPhone 6 or iPhone 6+, so when using a full screen image you may need to handle it manually via code.

What I'm doing (and it's not pretty but it works), is to include another Image Set for iPhone 6 (I all it imageName_47), and another one for iPhone 6+ (I call it imageName_55). Then in code, detect the screen size and swap the image to the best size. You'll only need the @2x version for the _47 one, and the @3x version for the _55 one.